Numeric keyboard not working on Chrome/Edge incognito window
today I found out that HTML numeric input doesn't lead to show a numeric keyboard on touchscreen devices such as Surface when using Chrome or Edge incognito window..
You can check it with this sample
I couldn't find any related topic on the web, so does anybody know what the reason is? and also is there any way to fix this behavior in incognito window?
